# Assign title in tableview in parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have lots of sections with the following data structure from parse database. I have no idea how to set it into array and display it correctly in repective tableview section in swift.

## section 1 title

### Smaller Subheader

### Smaller Subheader

### Smaller Subheader

### Smaller Subheader

## section 2 title

### Smaller Subheader

### Smaller Subheader

### Smaller Subheader

### Smaller Subheader

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {

    var name:String = "XXX"
    var query = PFQuery(className: "category")
    query.whereKey("type", equalTo:"\(Item)")
    query.whereKey("section", equalTo:i)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            println("Successfully retrieved ")

               let name = object["title"] as String

        } else {

            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }

   return name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure should be an array of your custom objects(depending on your values):

```
class yourClass
{
    var sectionTitle = ""
    var subData:[String] = [] //Here you can define array of AnyObject
}


var yourData:[yourClass] = []
```

After you get the data from Parse, you just loop through your parsed data and add it to your data structure:

```
var tmp = yourClass()
tmp.sectionTitle = "someSection"
tmp.subData = ["First subtitle","Second subtitle", "Thirt subtitle"]

yourData.append(tmp)
```

Then you have your data sorted like this:

```
yourData[0].sectionTitle //This is your first section title

yourData[1].sectionTitle //This is your second section title

yourData[0].subData[0] //This is your first subtitle in your first section
```

And so on...

Comment: i understand your rational to create a class. But i have no idea how to go ahead as my data is from parse. What i need to do is to call out different titles for the tableview title and content for the respective cell.